# Why won't Gazebo start ROS?

Tags: c++, simulation, ros

I am working through the Gazebo tutorial to connect a Gazebo sensor to ROS and pass messages. http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i6

This program builds a Gazebo ModelPlugin object, and initializes ROS from within this object. Then, it creates a ROS node, subscriber, queue, and a standard thread to run the ROS queue. This program works using Gazebo's transport objects, but when I try to add in ROS transport objects (as noted previously), the program does not work. My issue stems from the fact that the roscore nodes (including rosmaster) do not initialize.

My code for the sensor plugin is below. ROS integration begins on line 70:

```
#ifndef _VELODYNE_PLUGIN_HH_
#define _VELODYNE_PLUGIN_HH_

#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <gazebo/msgs/msgs.hh>
#include <gazebo/physics/physics.hh>
#include <gazebo/transport/transport.hh>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <ros/callback_queue.h>
#include <ros/subscribe_options.h>
#include <thread>
#include <std_msgs/Float32.h>

namespace gazebo
{
  /// \brief A plugin to control a Velodyne sensor.
  class VelodynePlugin : public ModelPlugin
  {
    /// \brief Constructor
    public: VelodynePlugin() {}

    /// \brief The load function is called by Gazebo when the plugin is
    /// inserted into simulation
    /// \param[in] _model A pointer to the model that this plugin is
    /// attached to.
    /// \param[in] _sdf A pointer to the plugin's SDF element.
    public: virtual void Load(physics::ModelPtr _model, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf) {
            gzwarn << "HERE";
      if (_model->GetJointCount() == 0) {
        std::cerr <<
          "Invalid joint count, Velodyne plugin not loaded\n";
      }

      // Store the model pointer for convenience.
      this->model = _model;

      // Get the first joint. We are making an assumption about the
      // model having one joint that is the rotational joint.
      this->joint = _model->GetJoints()[0];

      // Setup a P-controller with a gain of 0.1.
      this->pid=common::PID(0.1,0,0);

      // Apply the P-controller to the joint.
      this->model->GetJointController()->SetVelocityPID(
          this->joint->GetScopedName(), this->pid);

      // Default to zero velocity
      double velocity=0;

      // Check that the velocity element exists, then read the value
      if (_sdf->HasElement("velocity"))
        velocity=_sdf->Get<double>("velocity");

      this->SetVelocity(velocity);

      // Create the node
      this->node = transport::NodePtr(new transport::Node());
      this->node->Init(this->model->GetWorld()->GetName());

      // Create a topic name
      std::string topicName = "~/" + this->model->GetName() +
        "/vel_cmd";

      // Subscribe to the topic, and register a callback.
      this->sub = this->node->Subscribe(topicName,
          &VelodynePlugin::OnMsg, this);

            // Initialize ros, if it has not already been initialized.
            if (!ros::isInitialized()) {
                std::cout << "initializing ros" << std::endl;
                int argc = 0;
                char **argv=NULL;
                ros::init(argc,argv,"gazebo_client",
                    ros::init_options::NoSigintHandler);
            } else { std::cout << "NOT initializing ros" << std::endl; }

            // Create our ROS node. This acts in a similar manner to the
            // Gazebo node.
            this->rosNode.reset(new ros::NodeHandle("gazebo_client"));

      // Create a named topic, and subscribe to it.
      ros::SubscribeOptions so =
        ros::SubscribeOptions::create<std_msgs::Float32>(
            "/"+this->model->GetName()+"/vel_cmd",
            1,
            boost::bind(&VelodynePlugin::OnRosMsg, this, _1),
            ros::VoidPtr(), &this->rosQueue);

      this->rosSub = this->rosNode->subscribe(so);

      // Spin up the queue helper thread
      this->rosQueueThread = 
        std::thread(std::bind(&VelodynePlugin::QueueThread,this));
    }

    /// \brief Set the velocity of the Velodyne
    /// \param[in] _vel New target velocity
    public: void SetVelocity(const double &_vel) {
      // Set the joint's target velocity.
      this->model->GetJointController()->SetVelocityTarget(
          this->joint->GetScopedName(), _vel);
    }

    /// \brief Handle incoming message
    /// \param[in] _msg Repurpose a vector3 message. This function will
    /// only use the x component.
    private: void OnMsg(ConstVector3dPtr &_msg) {
      this->SetVelocity(_msg->x());
    }

    /// \brief Handle an incoming message from ROS
    /// \param[in] _msg A float value that is used to set the velocity
    /// of the Velodyne.
    public: void OnRosMsg(const std_msgs::Float32ConstPtr &_msg) {
      this->SetVelocity(_msg->data);
    }

    /// \brief ROS helper function that processes messages
    private: void QueueThread() {
      static const double timeout = .01;
      while (this->rosNode->ok()) {
        this->rosQueue.callAvailable(ros::WallDuration(timeout));
      }
    }


    /// \brief Pointer to the model;
    private: physics::ModelPtr model;

    /// \brief Control surfaces joints.
    private: physics::JointPtr joint;

    /// \brief Velocity PID for the propeller.
    private: common::PID pid;

    /// \brief A node used for transport
    private: transport::NodePtr node;

    /// \brief A subscriber to a named topic.
    private: transport::SubscriberPtr sub;

    /// \brief A node used for ROS transport
    private: std::unique_ptr<ros::NodeHandle> rosNode;

    /// \brief A ROS subscriber
    private: ros::Subscriber rosSub;

    /// \brief A ROS callbackqueue that helps process messages
    private: ros::CallbackQueue rosQueue;

    /// \brief A thread that keeps running the rosQueue
    private: std::thread rosQueueThread;

  };

  // Tell Gazebo about this plugin, so that Gazebo can call Load on this plugin.
  GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(VelodynePlugin)
}
#endif
```

Let me know how I can be more specific about this question. The first problem is definitely that ROS is not initialized. I can tell this because a call in a different terminal to `rostopic list` outputs:

```
ERROR: Unable to communicate with master
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the program does not work"? Do you get any error message or does the subscriber just never get any messages? In the latter case, did you verify with `rostopic echo /topic_name` that the messages are indeed published?

Comment: Ah and another question: How exactly do you start gazebo? Is it running from a terminal?

Comment: I start gazebo with 'gazebo ~/.gazebo/worlds/velodyne.world' from the bash terminal, which is where my world containing the object that I intend to communicate with ros is placed.

Comment: By "the program does not work", I mean that rosmaster/roscore is not initialized/started. When I try to run 'rostopic list', I receive the output: "ERROR: Unable to communicate with master"

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like `roscore` is not running. You have to run `roscore` manually before you can start any ROS node.

You can imagine `roscore` as a server to which all nodes connect and that manages the communication between these nodes. It won't start automatically, so you always have to start `roscore` as a first step, before you can use any ROS nodes.

An exception to this is, if you are using launch-files. `roslaunch` will indeed automatically start `roscore` if it is not already running.

Comment: This is an interesting point. I had assumed that ros::init() would start roscore. I have actually tried to manually start roscore so that I can communicate with rosmaster. In a seperate terminal, 'rostopic list' shows only /rosout and /rosout_agg as available topics. A call to 'rostopic pub /{my_topic} /{my_msg_type}' outputs 'publishing and latching message.'This leads me to believe that this process is hanging.' In conclusion, I believe that starting roscore is not the issue. I will continue to research. Thanks! Let me know what you think!

Comment: @errolflynn: I can't verify it right now (no ROS installed), but I think the message you get from `rostopic pub` is okay (so this is working as expected).

Comment: This message is fine, however it should publish a message that then translates into a command sent to my ROS-compatible object. When I publish this message with 'rostopic pub', The published message is not received or does not do anything to the ROS-compatible object.

Comment: @errolflynn When you run `rostopic echo /topic_name` in one terminal and then publish a message with `rostopic pub` in another terminal, does the echo-command receive the message?

Comment: Yes, the echo command receives the data. And a call to 'rostopic list' shows the command that I am publishing.

Comment: Okay, so it seems that ROS is okay and it is only an issue with the gazebo node. Did you double-check that you are subscribing to the correct topic? If you run `rosnode list` while your gazebo node is running, is gazebo_client listed in the output?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved via running `roscore` beforehand you start Gazebo server. I must accept that the tutorial does, indeed, follows a Gazebo-first pipeline. Nonetheless, I believe it's a deprecated method to make the bridge between ROS and Gazebo. You should inspect the code in [gazebo-ros-pkgs](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/tree/kinetic-devel/gazebo_plugins) for a much easier method.

A Gazebo plugin is a run-time component -shared library in technical terms- that is attached to a specific object or directly to the [World](https://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1World.html) instance via SDF/URDF files. A world instance can be simulated through the command `gzserver <world_file>`. If you are using Gazebo in conjunction with ROS *(I highly recommend that if you are going to use ROS at some point)*, what you need is **gazebo-ros** node. Again in the above link, there are several examples of how it is done.

In ROS universe, all the processes are represented as ROS nodes and Gazebo simulator is not different. When you use `gazebo_ros` package (which makes the ROS-Gazebo connection in one-line) Gazebo simulator is initialized as `/gazebo` node with the specified world file and all the attached Gazebo plugins do operate as components within this node. The first issue resides in here. You should not call `ros::init()` in a Gazebo plugin since it has already an initialized node. Second problem is in your assumption, such that `ros::init()` call does not start the `roscore` node. It only initializes your executable in a way that it can communicate with other ROS nodes under the same master. So, what you need is only a [ros::NodeHandle](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html).

I don't know why OSRF hasn't updated the tutorials. Perhaps, they are strictly trying to offer a Gazebo-first aspect in Gazebo website and treat ROS as a secondary component. However I find it rather problematic, especially when one wants to use ROS as primary component. Since `roslaunch` only launches ROS nodes, which makes `gzserver <world_file>` command disfunctional, this tutorial would be invalid and even contradicting with the mainstream usage.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, Gazebo is not part of ROS, so it makes sense if it doesn't start `roscore`.

If you want to start `roscore` simultaneously as this node starts, try to use `roslaunch` command instead of rosrun.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is indeed `roscore` but after that you can check the node ur started with `rosnode info nodename` to check the sub and publisher status or do `roswtf` to check for error in general.

You can check realtime debug log setting ros debug level with rqt logger level(easiest way) to know if your node is getting data or not